# Extracting the parameters of a function nested in an interface in Typescript

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to construct a function with a different return type in the following example?

```
interface APIResponse<T> {
  code: T;
}

interface Registry {
  a: {
    get: (dc: string, id: string) => string;
  };
  b: {
    get: (id: string) => string;
    list: () => string[];
  };
}

function callService<
  T extends keyof Registry,
  R extends keyof Registry[T],
  F extends Registry[T][R]
>(
  svc: T,
  method: R,
  callback: (
    ...args: Parameters<F>        // Type 'Registry[T][string] | Registry[T][number] | Registry[T][symbol]' is not assignable to type '(...args: any) => any'.
  ) => APIResponse<ReturnType<F>> // Type 'Registry[T][string] | Registry[T][number] | Registry[T][symbol]' is not assignable to type '(...args: any) => any'.
) {}

// although the above has a type error, the arguments and return type here are correctly inferred by vscode:
callService("a", "get", (dc, id) => ({ code: dc + id }));
```

If I hardcode the service and method name the compiler is happy:

```
function callService2<
  T extends keyof Registry,
  R extends keyof Registry[T],
>(
  svc: T,
  method: R,
  callback: (
    ...args: Parameters<Registry["a"]["get"]>  // this is fine
  ) => APIResponse<ReturnType<Registry["a"]["get"]>>  // this is fine
) {}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an open issue in GitHub, [microsoft/TypeScript#21760](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21760), pointing out that nested generic property lookups fail to be assignable to the expected subproperty constraints.  The issue is listed as a bug, and there might have been some effort to address it, but it looks like not much is happening with it right now.

In your case, it means that the type `Registry[T][R]` is not seen as assignable to any function type, despite the fact that it *must* be a function type.  I would suggest, as a workaround, to use something more forgiving than the [`Parameters`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype) and [`ReturnType`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype) utility types provided by the standard library.  For example:

```
type Params<T> = T extends (...args: infer P) => any ? P : never;
type RetType<T> = T extends (...args: any) => infer R ? R : never;

function callService<
  T extends keyof Registry,
  R extends keyof (Registry[T]),
  >(
    svc: T,
    method: R,
    callback: (
      ...args: Params<Registry[T][R]>
    ) => APIResponse<RetType<Registry[T][R]>>
  ) { }
```

As an aside, note that your original code doesn't have a good inference site for `F`, and so it will fall back to its constraint, `Registry[T][R]`.  You don't even want `F` to be anything *narrower* than `Registry[T][R]`, right?  So I've removed `F` entirely and replaced it with `Registry[T][R]`.

Anyway, the difference between `Params`/`RetType` and `Parameters`/`ReturnType` is that the new versions do not try to constrain their type parameters to anything.  If you evaluate `Params<T>` and `RetType<T>` on a non-function type `T` like `string`, it will result in `never`.  Otherwise it's the same as `Parameters<T>` and `ReturnType<T>`.  That relaxed restriction is enough to stop the compiler from worrying that it can't  guarantee that `Registry[T][R]` is a function type.

Of course it will turn out that when you *call* `callService()` that, for any actual specifications of `T` and `R`, `Registry[T][R]` will be a function and the type of `callback` will be as expected:

```
callService("a", "get", (dc, id) => ({ code: dc + id }));
// function callService<"a", "get">(
//   svc: "a", method: "get", callback: (dc: string, id: string) => APIResponse<string>
// ): void
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIIAUCSAlCBnABwHsQ8IAeAFQD5kBvAKGWQSIBMIAuZSgbgYC+DBqEixEKXAHNgeMFACe9JsjjdGzZlIhhuACjYJucqKCkAaZMDbH5ZgJTIAvLRNneyFQP7MARupUtHX1rW1MQKUcXZDcIn00AG1ldZD0o1zsIgG0AXXjvQWEwBQIUdDgoOABbPCpaJx5kCAAPSBA2PFSAOh6KqTxuUBhoZHR01RAlAH5R5G4QCAA3aH5i0uRcMEoSihpnRpa2ju7eqH7uOEnxoZHsZBm7+aWV4RgAVxAEMGASFjgEhIAZWgi2ASHIKkoTVaEHanQA1hAFEQYBsIDITApzCo7odYcdEcjUXppMlFFlKDl7NjmNQ9IEYosjDwaZoqjoABbsbjYVnMBD-BK+RDw-QM5g9Lp9AajCrVWqkzEUnJZbA5agM8YYHD4YikCibbalciK+QKZWq9Ua5iOOjIIQMAUA4FQUFIPQAIjgHssHu0YB9qUMlms4z0dtYHG4hmQAGorGx7fZ7PwAPSp5DvT7fX5OoEgsEUL2Bv06D10vBM7jFyzssBcmzIUsByx54UIUVB5mxCwJsIOZy0bW4QgkMjkHvUezcRZEazCBcMIA)

Answer (score 1):

If you enforce that the shape of `Registry` is predicable in later generic types:

```
type RegistryBase = Record<string, Record<string, ((...args: any) => any)>>

interface Registry extends RegistryBase {
    a: {
        get: (dc: string, id: string) => string;
    };
    b: {
        get: (id: string) => string;
        list: () => string[];
    };
}
```

All your other types fall into place.

[Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIIAUCSAlCBnABwHsQ8IAeAFQD5kBvAKGWeQSIBMIAuZSgbgYBfBgzABPAilwBzYHjBQxAIThlkAXmS42UduXlRQ0gDRaIOvQaOmAFDYB0juFGl4ecEGICUG2h+-U1AygkLCIUhCyBmLIEAAekCDseGZRCsqqKIwsyHA82Tks0hBgPDbsCDxWICbIwOxVCkY+6rTV0gI5gp0sAEb5TIXMxaXINvWNhjUtbU01PUMANnKjNjPI7QDaALoLyN1CIgwwAK4gCGDAJKxwi4sAytAAbsBI5IPMlLEJEEkpANYQMREGCpFaKYwfLTfRLJZCA4GgmTgsSbSjbSE5ABiMN+cOR0TR2022G2DGoNiheCelV4mJYAFsSgALDg8bD05gIW6LXqIf5lKE5Rz2ZyuHjoZxwJmhPDkLFBHLrDA4fDEUgUXBgE5QECUCQUBVBHx0fYibl3R5QF5IGwAIjgdtMdpGTrGFVM9XWNlNbE4PAqyAA1HV2PsvF4+EA)